# UITableView crashes on iOS 9 when endUpdates is called with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad

After users upgraded to iOS 9, we've noticed a series of Bad Access (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`) crashes that don't appear for users who are still on iOS 8. It happens when we call `endUpdates` on UITableView.

The crash logs include the following reasons:

> Selector name found in current argument registers:
>   numberOfRowsInSection:
>
> Selector name found in current argument registers:
>   indexPathForRowAtGlobalRow:

Stack trace #1:

```
1   UIKit   __46-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]_block_invoke + 92
2   UIKit   __46-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]_block_invoke1007 + 224
3   UIKit   -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] + 2556
4   UIKit   -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 12892
[...]
```

Stack trace #2:

```
1   UIKit   __46-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]_block_invoke + 100
2   UIKit   -[UITableViewRowData globalRowForRowAtIndexPath:] + 102
3   UIKit   __46-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]_block_invoke1007 + 182
4   UIKit   -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] + 2300
5   UIKit   -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 10552
```

We are able to repro the issue, but don't have any clue on how to go about fixing it.

Comment: [Here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11137) you have some people dealing with the same and some potential solutions

Comment: `endUpdates` usually crashes when number of rows in tableView doesn't match number of items in a dataSource. Is there anything more in the console ?

Comment: @scope We've confirmed that it isn't the mismatched # of items issue that you typically see with `endUpdates` crashes.

Comment: I saw this crash as well. Was not related to an item mismatch. I fixed by removing beginUpdates and just reloading

Answer (score 8):

It looks like there's a bug in iOS9 when your UITableView has no rows that causes endUpdates to crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. To work around this bug, you have to call tableView reloadData before calling beginUpdates.

From the thread that [Claudio Redi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443185/uitableview-crashes-on-ios-9-when-endupdates-is-called-with-exc-bad-access#comment56628163_34443185) directed me to: [iOS9 iPad UITableView Crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) on 1st section insert](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11137), I've implemented the following workaround you add before calling `[tableView beginUpdates];`

```
if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion].majorVersion >= 9)
{
    // there's a bug in iOS9 when your UITableView has no rows that causes endUpdates to crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    // to work around this bug, you have to call tableView reloadData before calling beginUpdates.

    BOOL shouldReloadData = YES;
    NSInteger numberOfSections = [tableView.dataSource numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];
    for (NSInteger section = 0; section < numberOfSections; section++)
    {
        if ([tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] > 0)
        {
            // found a row in current section, do not need to reload data
            shouldReloadData = NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (shouldReloadData) 
    {
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: This one bit me in the butt too. Thanks for the fix. Perhaps it will be fixed with iOS 10.

Comment: I had this issue with a legacy app running on iOS10, so it would appear that its not fixed on iOS 10. Did anyone file a bug report with apple and get a resolution?

Comment: Still no fix as of now. Fun fun fun.

Comment: in ios 11. it is okay for me.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue as well, the answer above of calling `reloadData()` on the table view did resolve the issue, however this was not ideal, as the animation associated with the update was not fluid, due to the reload.

The root of the issue is that I had programmatically called `selectRow(at indexPath: IndexPath?, animated: Bool, scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition)` on the table view, for an invalid index path at the time the method was called. (The updates in the table view were to expand/collapse a section to show the rows within or zero rows, I would at times select a row in a collapsed section). This behaviour did not cause a crash when selecting a row for an index path that was not visible in the table view, however when updating the `UITableView` between `beginUpdates(`) and `endUpdates()` calls after selecting an invalid index path, there would be a crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the `endUpdates()` call. Adding a check before calling `selectRowAt:` to ensure the index path was visible/valid, before programmatically selecting resolved the crash without the need to call `reloadData()`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when attempting to do more than one of the insert, delete, or reload operations between the beginUpdates() and endUpdates() calls, like so

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRows(at: [deletePaths], with: .fade)
tableView.insertRows(at: [insertPaths], with: .fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

I was able to fix the issue by calling

```
performBatchUpdates(_ updates: (() -> Void)?, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

instead of using the begin and end calls, ex.

```
self.tableView.performBatchUpdates({
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [deletePaths], with: .fade)
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [insertPaths], with: .fade)
}, completion: nil)
```